# Running two instances of the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: scheduled-tasks, executorservice, instances

I have a number of asynchronous tasks to run in parallel. All the tasks can be divided into two types, lets call one - type A (that are time consuming) and everything else type B (faster and quick to execute ones). 
with a single ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with x poolsize, eventually at some point all threads are busy executing type A, as a resul type B gets blocked and delayed. 
what im trying to accomplish is to run a type A tasks parallel to type B, and i want tasks in both the types to run parallel within their group for performance .

Would you think its prudent to have two instances of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor for the type A and B exclusively with their own thread pools ? Do you see any issues with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's seems reasonable. 
I am doing something similar i.e. I need to execute tasks in serial fashion depending on some id e.g. all the tasks which are for component with id="1" need to be executed serially to each another and in parallel to all other tasks which are for components with different ids.
so basically I need a separate queue of tasks for each different component, the tasks are pulled one after another from each specific queue.
In order to achieve that I use

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new JobThreadFactory(componentId));
```

for each component.
Additionally I need ExecutorService for a different type of tasks which are not bound to componentIds, for that I create additional ExecutorService instance

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(DEFAULT_THREAD_POOL_SIZE, new JobThreadFactory());
```

This works fine for my case at least.
The only problem I can think of if there is a need of ordered execution of the tasks i.e.
task2 NEEDS to be executed after task1 and so on... But I doubt this the case here ...

Comment: Sounds good. On a saperate note on your choice of using the Executor util vs an implementation like ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. any specific reason? Also what does you JobThreadFactory class do. (wondering if this should be a saperate Qs?)

Comment: I use java.util.concurrent.Executors factory methods because those are shielding me from the complex constructors of the concrete ExecutorService implementations. For example the newSingleThreadExecutor factory method calls the 6 params ThreadPoolExecutor constructor... The drawback of this is that you don't have control over the queue impl used to hold the tasks which are waiting execution and this could lead to some memory leaks etc (if the tasks are executed slower than submitted for execution). Factory can be used for naming the threads(like I do), logging task exec start, end, etc...